# Toggle Button Pixi JS

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

i'm new in JS and learning Pixi JS
i have no idea about toggle button in my little project. got dead end
i want to do some click button 'Mute' and the function is mute also change to icon mute, when i click this mute button, the icon will change back to unmute icon

here my some script

let's call this "ButtonView"

```html
import { GlowFilter } from "pixi-filters";
import { Timeline } from "gsap/gsap-core";

export default class ButtonView extends PIXI.Container {
    constructor(options) {
        super()
        this.name = options.name || 'button'
        this.text = options.text || 'button'
        this.action = options.action || this.noAction

        this.timeLine = new Timeline()
        this.outlineFilter = new GlowFilter({ outerStrength: 0, color: 0xffffff, distance: 20 })
        this.filters = [this.outlineFilter]

        this.setInteractive(true)
        this.on('click', this.action)
        this.on('tap', this.action)
        this.on('pointerup', this.pointerUp)
        this.on('pointerdown', this.pointerDown)
        this.on('pointerover', this.pointerOver)
        this.on('pointerout', this.pointerOut)
    }

    setInteractive(bool) {
        this.interactive = bool
        this.buttonMode = bool
    }

    pointerUp() {
        this.scale.set(1)
    }

    pointerDown() {
        this.scale.set(0.95)
    }

    pointerOver() {
        this.timeLine.clear()
        this.timeLine.to(this.outlineFilter, .3, { outerStrength: 2 })
    }

    pointerOut() {
        this.timeLine.clear()
        this.timeLine.to(this.outlineFilter, .3, { outerStrength: 0 })
    }

    enable() {
        this.setInteractive(true)
    }

    disable() {
        this.setInteractive(false)
    }

    noAction() {
        console.log('ButtonView no action')
    }
}
```

and this "MuteView"

```html
import ButtonView from "./ButtonView"

export default class MuteView extends ButtonView {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options)
        this.header = new PIXI.Text('mute', { fill: 0xeeeeee, fontSize: 20 })
        this.muted = new PIXI.Text(options.muted, { fill: 0xffffff, fontSize: 40, fontWeight: 'bold' })
        this.addChild(this.header, this.muted)
        this.create()
    }

    create() {
        const btnMute = new PIXI.Sprite('./images/mute_box.png')
        btnMute.anchor.set(0.5)

        this.btnSprite = new PIXI.Sprite('./images/unmute_icon.png')
        this.btnSprite.position.set(
            btnMute.width / 2 - this.btnSprite.width / 2,
            btnMute.height / 2 - this.btnSprite.height / 2
        )
        this.btnSprite.anchor.set(0.5)

        const back = new PIXI.Graphics()
        back.drawRect(0, 0, btnMute.width, btnMute.height)
        back.pivot.set(mute.width / 2)

        this.btn = new PIXI.Container()
        this.btn.addChild(btnMute, this.btnSprite)
        this.addChild(back, this.btn)
    }

    pointerUp() {
        this.btn.scale.set(1)
    }

    pointerDown() {
        this.btn.scale.set(0.95)
    }

    enable() {
        super.enable()
        this.spriteChange('./images/unmute_icon.png')
    }

    disable() {
        super.disable()
        this.spriteChange('./images/mute_icon.png')
    }

    spriteChange(texture) {
        this.btnSprite.texture = texture
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the "interactivity" example? What exactly are you stuck on? https://pixijs.io/examples/#/interaction/interactivity.js

Comment: the button won't change when i click that 'Mute Button'. it working, but not my expectation. what i want is from function mute to function unmute, also the icon on button change too
i'm stuck that icon button won't change to anything. :(

Comment: if i use interactivity example, it only consider change a while when mouse hover to button. but it didn't change directly after click the button

thanks for reply

Comment: Please provide the minimal code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Maybe you can paste the code on codesandbox or https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit so we can see what you're trying to achieve. At first glance your code seems a bit overwrought if all you want is to enable/disable a button and change an icon. I would think you don't need that many children and extending a class. Just change the texture and keep the "muted / unmuted" state in a boolean variable.

Comment: Okay. i will try when i'm not in working time. Thanks for your reply